# What are the implications of BTRFS read errors?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

I am seeing the following read errors:

```
# btrfs device stats /mnt/data
[/dev/sda].write_io_errs    0
[/dev/sda].read_io_errs     0
[/dev/sda].flush_io_errs    0
[/dev/sda].corruption_errs  0
[/dev/sda].generation_errs  0
[/dev/sdd].write_io_errs    0
[/dev/sdd].read_io_errs     53
[/dev/sdd].flush_io_errs    0
[/dev/sdd].corruption_errs  0
[/dev/sdd].generation_errs  0
[/dev/sdc].write_io_errs    0
[/dev/sdc].read_io_errs     0
[/dev/sdc].flush_io_errs    0
[/dev/sdc].corruption_errs  0
[/dev/sdc].generation_errs  0
```

What could the implications of this be? As they are just read errors would this likely just be some bit flip in RAM that caused the checksum to not match, or could this imply persisted data is corrupted?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the output of `dmesg`?

Comment: This shows nothing: `dmesg | grep -i btrfs`

Comment: not `dmesg | grep -i 'error\|fail'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `man 8 btrfs-device`:

> ```
>    write_io_errs
>        Failed writes to the block devices, means that the layers beneath
>        the filesystem were not able to satisfy the write request.
>
>    read_io_errors
>        Read request analogy to write_io_errs.
> ```

Based on that, I'd take it to mean there's potential that there are problems with the device.